# How to set max-age for non static file responses

Tags: node.js, express

How to set the max-age parameter for non static file responses in expressjs.

My Code:

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.set({'maxAge':5}); 
    res.send("Hello Message from port: " + port);
    res.status(200).end()
})
```

I tried this:

```
    res.set({'max-age':5});
```

Also this:

```
    res.set({'Cache-Control':'max-age=5'});
```

It is working fine with `res.SendFile(file,{maxAge: 5})`
But the problem with the static files is I see the 'max-age' reflecting in the header only on the first http response after the server is started.

All the subsequent response headers show 'max-age = 0' even if the file is served fresh (status 200)

Comment: if You're proxy passing request using nginx, it's better to set headers in nginx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't set the header with:

```
res.set({'maxAge':5});
```

or:

```
res.set({'max-age':5});
```

because instead of setting the `Cache-Control` header it would set `maxAge` or `max-age` headers, respectively, which are not valid HTTP headers.

You can set it with:

```
res.set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=5');
```

or:

```
res.set({'Cache-Control': 'max-age=5'});
```

See:

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=5');
    res.send("Hello Message from port: " + port);
    res.status(200).end()
});
```

You can use curl to see the headers:

```
curl -v http://localhost:3333/hello
```

(just use your port instead of 3333)

If it doesn't include your `Cache-Control` header on every response then maybe some middleware is messing up your headers, or maybe you have a proxy server that changes them.

Also keep in mind that you're using `max-age` of 5 seconds so the caching is very short.

See:

- https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: The intention is to make cache very short. But I figured out the problem. As you said, it is the proxy server which is messing up. I'm load-balancing two express servers using HAProxy. Thanks again.